# Switch camera on surface texture android

Tags: android, camera, textureview

I want to do switch camera when user click the switch camera button.

In my application am using surface texture instead of surfaceview how should i call setDisplay on switching camera.

Comment: The question is pretty straight forward as worded. Did you try to call setDisplay() and if so what happened?

Answer (score 0):

Switching camera (from *back-facing* to *front-facing* or vice versa) on Android means essentially that you close the first camera completely and start the other one from scratch. There are no shortcuts. You must follow exactly the same path as when you started.

On some recent devices, it is possible to have two opened cameras at the same time. This can reduce switching time significantly.

Comment: I can start from the beginning after switching camera,problem is start preview and camera suraface texture declared in surface created call back

Comment: You're not really explaining what the problem is.  If you can do it once (e.g. `mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mCameraTexture)`), why can't you do it again after switching cameras?

Comment: OK, I think I understand the question. You don't have to wait for `SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceCreated()` to call `Camera.startPreview()`. You can use the existing instance. One case to care about is what happens when your app goes off-screen (e.g. user presses Home button) and when it is reactivated. The user expects probably that the same camera will become active.